# Valid instances not drawn

Tags: libgdx

i have a problem with my code, my valid instances aren't drawn.

I'm just at the beginning so i will post the whole code(which sounds bigger than it is)..just a few lines

```
public class MyGame implements ApplicationListener {
PerspectiveCamera cam;
Environment environment;
ModelBatch batch;
AssetManager assetManager;
Array<GameObject> instances;
ArrayMap<String, GameObject.Creater> creater;

//for debugging
CameraInputController camController;
//for debugging

//////////statics
public static float fieldOfView = 67;
public static float screenWidth;
public static float screenHeight;
public static final float camNear = 1;
public static final float camFar = 300;
public static Vector3 camPosition = new Vector3(5f, 9f, 10f);
public static Vector3 camLookAt = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
//environment
public static final float ambientLightRed = 1f;
public static final float ambientLightGreen = 1f;
public static final float ambientLightBlue = 1f;
public static final float ambientLightAlpha = 1f;
//environment
//////////statics
@Override
public void create() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    screenWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    screenHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

    batch = new ModelBatch();

    //bullet goes here
    //Bullet.init();
    //bullet

    //cam goes here
    cam = new PerspectiveCamera(fieldOfView, screenWidth, screenHeight);
    cam.near = camNear;
    cam.far = camFar;
    cam.position.set(camPosition);
    cam.lookAt(camLookAt);
    cam.update();
    camController = new CameraInputController(cam);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(camController);
    //cam

    //environment goes here
    environment = new Environment();
    environment.set(new ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.AmbientLight, ambientLightRed, ambientLightGreen, ambientLightBlue, ambientLightAlpha));
    //environment

    //assets go here
    assetManager = new AssetManager();
    assetManager.load("dirtyhuman.g3db", Model.class);
    assetManager.load("platform.g3db", Model.class);
    assetManager.finishLoading();
    //assets

    //models go here
    Model dirtyHuman = assetManager.get("dirtyhuman.g3db");
    Model platform = assetManager.get("platform.g3db");
    //model

    //arraymap goes here
    creater = new ArrayMap<String, GameObject.Creater>(String.class, GameObject.Creater.class);
    creater.put("dirtyHuman", new GameObject.Creater(dirtyHuman, "dirtyHuman"));
    creater.put("platform", new GameObject.Creater(platform, "platform"));
    //arraymap


    //modelinstances go here


    instances = new Array<GameObject>();
    instances.add(creater.get("dirtyHuman").create());
    instances.add(creater.get("platform").create());
    //modelinstances

    for(GameObject instance : instances)
    {
        Log.e("instances","" + instance);
    }


}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void render() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //update cam
    cam.update();
    //update cam

    //clear buffers
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    //clear buffers

    batch.begin(cam);
    batch.render(instances, environment);
    batch.end();
}

@Override
public void pause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void resume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.e("Application Dispose","true");
    batch.dispose();
    instances.clear();
    assetManager.dispose();



    for(GameObject.Creater creater : this.creater.values())
    {
        creater.dispose();
    }
}

//////////////////////class gameobject
public static class GameObject extends ModelInstance implements Disposable {
    public GameObject(Model model, String node) {
        super(model, node);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("GameObject.Creater Dispose","true");
    }

    static class Creater implements Disposable {
        Model model;
        String node;
        public Creater(Model model, String node) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.model = model;
            this.node = node;
        }

        public GameObject create() {
            return new GameObject(model, node);
        }

        @Override
        public void dispose() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.e("GameObject Dispose","true");
            model.dispose();
        }

    }


}
//////////////////////class gameobject
```

}

So basically i'm just loading a `dirtyHuman` and a `platform`. Everything works fine till i implemented my static `GameObject` which extends `ModelInstance`. It's Kind of a factory class because the nested class `Creater` is responsible for creating the new GameObject. After that my Screen stays empty(no human drawn, no platform drawn). I will not mention on which devices i have tested it because it's  surely no device depending problem..

I hope somebody can find the fault and make it clear to me what i actual did wrong.

Comment: Narrow down the problem. Which of your methods does the rendering? Is it being called? Why or why not?

Comment: @anko See my own answere from 7.02. ! ;) but thanks for your support anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the Problem. Looking at the `source` of `ModelInstance` this part shows why it can't work:

```
public ModelInstance (final Model model, final Matrix4 transform, final String nodeId, boolean recursive, 
128         boolean parentTransform, boolean mergeTransform, boolean shareKeyframes) { 
129         this.model = model; 
130         this.transform = transform == null ? new Matrix4() : transform; 
131         nodePartBones.clear(); 
132         Node copy, node = model.getNode(nodeId, recursive); 
133         this.nodes.add(copy = copyNode(node)); 
134         if (mergeTransform) { 
135             this.transform.mul(parentTransform ? node.globalTransform : node.localTransform); 
136             copy.translation.set(0, 0, 0); 
137             copy.rotation.idt(); 
138             copy.scale.set(1, 1, 1); 
139         } else if (parentTransform && copy.hasParent()) this.transform.mul(node.getParent().globalTransform); 
140         setBones(); 
141         copyAnimations(model.animations, shareKeyframes); 
142         calculateTransforms(); 
143     }
```

It doesn't render anything because of line `132`. I thought i can give my `new GameObject` a `nodeID` which is not similar to the `nodeID` in the crreater application ( for instance `Blender`). But he fetches the node from the `nodeID` which i put to the `constructor`. So if i put a `nodeID` which doesn't exist in the `Model` he surely can't find anything.